# Dropzone.js doesn't store images in folder

Tags: php, dropzone

I have a small problem with the usage of Dropzone.js about uploading images. When I try to upload an image, the upload seems to be successful but I don't find any images in my folder. I give you my codes below :

uploadPhoto.php:

```
<?php

    $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    $dossier = 'public/photos';

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

        $temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $chemin = dirname(__FILE__) . $ds . $dossier . $ds;

        $fichier = $chemin . $_FILES['file']['name'];

        move_uploaded_file($temp, $fichier);

    }
?>
```

fileUploader.html.twig :

```
<div id="photo" class="dropzone"></div><br>
<script src="{{ asset('js/fileuploader/dropzone.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $('div#photo').dropzone({
        url: 'php/uploadPhoto.php',
        maxFilesize: 5,
        acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png',
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictDefaultMessage: "Placez vos photos ici en cliquant ou en les déplacant dans le cadre",
        dictInvalidFileType: "Le format de votre photo doit être en '.jpg', '.jpeg' ou '.png'.",
        dictFileTooBig: "La taille du fichier doit être inférieure à 5Mb.",
        dictRemoveFile: "Supprimer photo"
    });
</script>
```

I'm working on a Symfony project so I had to create a separate .php file to make it "work".

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: i'd suggest to echo the $chemin and die; to see the right path u're sending ur file to,

Comment: if you're using symfony then for a better security and clean code, create the route and a controller file, and add your logic in that controller,
check this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html#creating-an-uploader-service

Comment: OK, I got a clue. My .php script is taking the path from its folder (the php folder), it looks like this : "/Users/administrateur/Documents/Cours/TFE/Travail/Retropedia/public/php/../public/photos/".
The problem is, when I try to go to the previous folder with a "..", it doesn't work either. I'm currently searching how I can fix this, I'll take a look further at the link you brought me. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I think I got what's wrong. I think it's the dirname() function. I'll check this immediately.

Comment: I just succeed how to fix it. I've change the dirname() parameter with an absolute path to recognize the folder. Thank you again for your help !